# Bash shellscript array elements are not ordered

Tags: bash, shell

I had this code, when I stored hostname to CustomHostName array, I expected it should store in order, it seems not stored correctly when i tried to print out or use that array

```
declare -A CustHostName
for i in "${UdmPodsList[@]}" ; do
    hostname=`kubectl get pods -n $NameSpace  -o wide|grep $i |awk '{print $7}'`
    CustHostName["$i"]="$hostname"
    echo "$hostname"
done
echo "${CustHostName[@]}"
```

echo $hostname, will print out as in this order

```
vudmvzcl00-worker-02
vudmvzcl00-worker-03
```

echo "${CustHostName[@]}", or used it in for loop, it had worker-03 as first element

```
 vudmvzcl00-worker-03 vudmvzcl00-worker-02
```

I am trying to sort the array but this is not what I wanted to do.

I want the vudmvzcl00-worker-02 to be first element to on the array list when I used.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of `i`? Why are you indexing the array elements by that?

Comment: Have you tried to use sort between grep and awk command?

Comment: @AndrewS : The problem seems to me that you are *not* using an array, but an associative array (`CustHostName["$i"]="$hostname"`), and they are by design unordered.

Comment: "*I expected it should store in order*" - in what order?

Comment: I meant when you used the array on the other languages, if you store first element into an array, then when I try to use it, that first element should be the first one on the list? Like you said, it is an associate array.  podname=sdma ~ vudmvzcl00-worker-02  and sdmb=vudmvzcl00-worker-03.  if I sort the array as UTLox comments below.  Then mapping might be wrong between podname and hostname.

Comment: You have an *associative* array, which is analogous to a Perl hash or a Python `dict` rather than an (integer-)indexed array.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
echo "${CustHostName[@]}"
```

with

```
for key in $(sort <<<"${!CustHostName[@]}"); do
   echo "${CustHostName[$key]}"
done
```

**explanation**

`${!CustHostName[@]}"` --> get the keys, not the values

Comment: I tried your way, it seems the result is same. The problem when I stored the element on associate array?  Ava:vudmvzcl00-worker-03
Ava:vudmvzcl00-worker-02

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way, it seems working for me.

```
CustomHostName=()
n=0
for i in "${UdmPodsList[@]}" ; do
   ((n++))
   hostname=`kubectl get pods -n $NameSpace  -o wide|grep $i |awk '{print $7}'`
   CustHostName[$n]="$hostname"
   echo "$hostname"
done
```

output as I expected. no sorting needed.

```
echo "${CustHostName[@]}"
vudmvzcl00-worker-02 vudmvzcl00-worker-03
```

Or print in the array.

```
for HOST in "${!CustHostName[@]}" ; do
   echo "${CustHostName[$HOST]}"
done
```

output(ArrayPrint):

```
vudmvzcl00-worker-02
vudmvzcl00-worker-03
```

Thanks.